# Should I offer a download with limited free service or registration?

Tags: marketing, data-collection, app, download

I am building an app that offers a service that aggregates various information to a user's mobile.

I want users to register when they download the app but am worried there might be a bigger drop off than if I offer a limited service immediately.

How can I investigate this further and what do you think I should do?

Comment: I would suggest you to describe the situation somewhat in more details so that giving answer to it will be easier.

Answer (score 2):

Does registering add value to the user? Personally, my recommended path for apps is:

- Provide immediate value to user, even if the value is limited
- Add more value when a user registers
- Make sure registering is as simple as possible (username/pwd or social login)
- If you want to collect more information about users (such as asking them to complete an account profile), add value in proportion to the information they provide

Answer (score 1):

Did you consider the following options?

1. **Simple registration:** Just email and password. Let the users fill in the
   rest of the profile later (you have to seduce the them to do so).
2. **Social login:** Use Facebook, Google or Twitter login.
3. **Limited use without registration:** Let the users have a taste of the
   app, with limited use and no registration. They have to register for
   full use.